# How to use the where method with two different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, where-clause, active-record-query

Hello Guys I have a question,
for example I have  a model `Product` who has 
`:title,  :description, :category_id`. And the product `belongs_to :category`
and I have a model `Category` who has `:name`. And `has_many :products`

I'm trying to do a scope who will use the method where. I try for example `Product.where(category_id: 2)` and I have all the products who was saved with the id=2. 
But my question is if I want to put in the clause where using the `category.name: 'some_category'`. How can I do?

Comment: Untested but try `Product.joins(:category).where(category: { name: "A Category Name"})`. Alternatively, `Category.find_by(name: "A Category Name").products`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a best answer for what I want to do and know I want to share here, first I install a `gem has_scope`.

Then in my Product model I do this scope:

```
scope :category, -> category_id {where(:category_id => category_id)}
```

Then in the products_controller I put:

```
has_scope :category
```

and

```
def index
    @products = apply_scopes(Product).all
end
```

And then in my navbar I put this links:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Oils', category: 1 %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Wines', category: 2 %></li>
```

and this was posible for show just these types of products by category.
But there has a problem with this!
It will work just if you click firstly in the Products.path where will show all the products and then if you click on these links will works fine. 
But when I click in other link like Contact.path and then click on Oils link it will show in the navigator /contact?category=1 and then will not show the products filtered like I want.

Then the solution for fix this problem was:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Azeites', '/products?category=1' %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Vinhos', '/products?category=2' %></li>
```

And every time you click will show perfectly, very simple and practice. Thank's guys for help me!

Answer (score 2):

```
Product.joins(:category).where(categories: { name: string_or_array_of_names })
```

using `string_or_array_of_names` as your variable

Comment: Im glad it worked! Please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: And other thing now I have the scope working I want to show the products filtered with the scope when a user click with a dropdown menu button on the navbar. How its posible?

Comment: You could use ajax to submit a form containing the drop down. Then in the ajax response you could edit the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `joins` and `references`.

```
Product.joins(:category).references(:category).where("categories.name = ?", "a name")
```

Comment: I have an error with this when I put on rails console:  
ArgumentError: The scope body needs to be callable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :by_category, ->(name) { joins(:category).where(categories: {name: name}) }
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@cars = Product.by_category("cars")
```

Comment: I try this and I get an error:  >> @z = Product.by_category("azeite")
  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "products"."category_id" WHERE "category"."name" = ?  [["name", "azeite"]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: category.name: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "products"."category_id" WHERE "category"."name" = ?

Comment: The `where` should be `categories` I think. Also, how are you passing your variables?